# How NOT to create a azurerm_mssql_database_extended_auditing_policy

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to deploy my infra with terraform.
I have a mssql server and database and using azurerm 2.32

While deploying mssql I'm getting following error

```
Error: issuing create/update request for SQL Server "itan-mssql-server" Blob Auditing Policies(Resource Group "itan-west-europe-resource-group"): sql.ExtendedServerBlobAuditingPoliciesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="DataSecurityInvalidUserSuppliedParameter" Message="Invalid parameter 'storageEndpoint'. Value should be a blob storage endpoint (e.g. https://MyAccount.blob.core.windows.net)."
```

I have already tried

1. defining extended_auditing_policy on database level - failed
2. defining extended_auditing_policy on server level - failed
3. defining azurerm_mssql_database_extended_auditing_policy on root level - failed
4. leaving empty extended_auditing_policy - failed

Global level of definition looks like this (^C^V from terraform documentation with adjustment to my project):

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_database_extended_auditing_policy" "db-policy" {
  database_id = azurerm_mssql_database.itan-mssql-database.id
  storage_endpoint = azurerm_storage_account.itan_storage_account.primary_blob_endpoint
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.itan_storage_account.primary_access_key
  storage_account_access_key_is_secondary = false
  retention_in_days = 1

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_mssql_database.itan-mssql-database,
    azurerm_storage_account.itan_storage_account]
}
```

I'm looking for one of two possible solutions:

- total disabling of audits (I don't really needed now)
- fixing error and enabling the audit

Thanks!
Jarek

Comment: It seems that is is wider issue https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/8915

Comment: I reproduced this error in `West Europe`, but all went fine in `North Europe`.

Comment: OK, thanks Krzysiek! Will keep an eye on that issue.

Comment: I converted my comment into reply. Please consider marking them as answer and upvoting it if it was helpful for you.

Comment: Any workarounds would be super helpful until this is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by [Breaking change in the SQL Extended Auditing Settings API](https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/issues/11271). Please check also this [issue in terraform provider](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/8915).

As a workaround you may try call [ARM template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-sql-auditing-server-policy-to-blob-storage) from terraform. However, I'm not sure if under the hood they use the same or different API.

Answer (score 0):

Workarund that looks to be working for me is like this:

I Followed tip by `[ddarwent][1]` from git hub:
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/8915#issuecomment-711029508

So basically its like this:

1. `terraform apply`
2. Go to `terraform.tfstate` delete "tainted mssql server"
3. `terraform apply`
4. Go to `terraform.tfstate` delete "tainted mssql database"
5. `terraform apply`

Looks like all my stuff is on and working